# How big can I go for a subpanel?

Tags: electrical-panel

I have 2 125 amp breakers for my main breakers.they are next to my meter.
What would my main breaker box be for amps?

Answer (score 1):

Since your main breakers are at the meter, each "main" panel can be as large as you please, but of course each must be at least 125A.  The 125A breaker protects the wire to each panel, and the panel itself.

Definitely don't scrimp; nobody on this forum ever complained about having too many spaces in their panel, but we get lots and lots of the other.

If you have two 2-pole breakers, you will need 2 panels.  Paralleling two feeders to 1 panel is not allowed except with very special equipment.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go for a 200A panel, so you have room for future possible service expansion, in case of huge overload the 125A breakers already present will trip.

Panels are rated UP TO, so using a 200A panel with 125A service is absolutely possible and code-compliant